# What type of roof rack/crossbar mounting is it?

Tags: suzuki, parts

My local Suzuki dealer said that the original roof racks/crossbars for my '06 Aerio  are discontinued by the manufacturer. I am looking for a replacement from alternative makers.

I wonder what is the name of the mounting type that I show on the pictures below (there are manufacturer-designed mounting points). The answer will hopefully allow me to search for compatible models online.

[image]
[image]

**Update** I ended up buying [SportRack SR1002 Roof Rack](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01BMCHDMC) for ~$150 USD at the moment of writing. The installation was a pain in the neck. The instructions are very misleading. Anyway, the product kind of works. I was able to put some lumber holders on it.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Normally one searches by make, model and year. That is a « hook & loop » type fixing. Check out Thule.

Comment: You have been given similar information here: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/73610/10976

Comment: OEM dealers are rarely worth bothering with for accessories if the car is over 10 years old - you're better off looking for an aftermarket one, from your local car parts store or online. Searching for "Suzuki Aerio Roof Rack" on eBay shows quite a few options, so that might be a good place to start

Comment: Igor, this might be better handled in the chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop It seems like you’re on a quest for suggestions (which the chat is great for) since you are actually shopping around for alternatives.